# Number of different probability terms in a joint distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, bayesian-network

I have learnt that the joint distribution of 5 variables will be having [(2^5)-1] = 31 different probability terms.

Could you please explain this to me?

Actually, I was going through Bayesian networks to figure out how the connections between nodes in the graph are modeled(in terms of probability and joint probability). The instructor went on to say that with 5 nodes in the graph, the joint distribution as per the Bayesian modeling would require only 10 probability terms whereas it would be 31 (for the same 5 nodes) when the Bayesian modeling is not used.

Comment: A little more context might be helpful.